# Matlab define a function

Tags: matlab, anonymous

I have a physical equation
P=(n R T/V - nb)-(an^2/V^2)

> which n,b,a,R are constants and V,T are independent variables
>
> the question said to construct an anonymous function (pressure)>P
> and then create a script function called (`vanderWall`) which return P,V,T and make mesh contour plot of (P,V,T) and plot of (P,V) for 10 values of T.

the function should generate T with limits T1 to T2 with nT steps, also generate V with limits V1 to V2 with nV steps

using these values for practical output
`T1=77`, `T2=800`, `nT=10`, `V1=35`, `V2=200`, `nV=150`, `n=1`, `a=55.37`, `b=30.4`.

I tried this code put no usefull answer

```
%constants
n=1;
a=55.37;
b=30.4;
R=8.314;

%anonymous function of independent variables V and T
Pressure=@(V,T) ((n*R.*T)./(V-n*b))-((a*n^2)./V.^2);

[P,V,T]=vanderWall(Pressure,77,800,10,35,200,150,1,55.37,30.4);

%function to return Pressure,Volume and Temperature
function[P,V,T]=vanderWall(Pressure,T1,T2,nT,V1,V2,nV,varargin)

%Volume and temperature generatd by function
T=T1:nT:T2;
V=V1:nV:V2;
P=Pressure(V,T);

%mesh contour plot between T,V and P
meshc(T,V,P)

%plot of V and P (isotherms)
plot(V,P)

end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no useful answer"? What is a useful answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try the following code for function `vanderWall`, where `[T,V]=meshgrid(t,v)` is the key step to make your code fly

```
function[P,V,T]=vanderWall(Pressure,T1,T2,nT,V1,V2,nV,varargin)

%Volume and temperature generatd by function
t = T1:nT:T2;
v = V1:nV:V2;
[T,V]=meshgrid(t,v);

P=Pressure(V,T);

%mesh contour plot between T,V and P
meshc(T,V,P)

%plot of V and P (isotherms)
plot(V,P)
end
```

---

Or you can apply the implicit singleton expansion (thanks for advice @CrisLuengo), i.e.,

```
function[P,V,T]=vanderWall(Pressure,T1,T2,nT,V1,V2,nV,varargin)

%Volume and temperature generatd by function
T = T1:nT:T2;
V = V1:nV:V2;

P=Pressure(V,T.')';

%mesh contour plot between T,V and P
meshc(T,V,P)

%plot of V and P (isotherms)
plot(V,P)
end
```

Comment: You don't need `meshgrid` any more in most cases, since the introduction of implicit singleton expansion. `P=Pressure(v,t.')'` should do the trick.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks, your information is added to the answer

Comment: thank you very much  I try both of these and it works

Comment: @FadheelaHussain You are welcome! If you think my answer is helpful, please feel free to upvote/accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that in your function you use both `V` and `T` as vectors. The way you use your anonymous function it is not clear, which `T` to divide by which `V`. 
I suppose you want all combinations - then you can substitute `V` by `V'` in your anonymous function.